# SharePoint 2013 Development enviroment

Tags: development, 2013, farm-solution

Can one develop SharePoint solutions without having installed SharePoint 2013 on local, development machine? 
There will be one 'test' machine, however it will be placed on other machine, to save resources.

I would like to develop farm solutions - this include: custom features, field types, webparts, actions, workflows, BDC. Also anything related with lists and contentTypes. 
Solutions should be deployed using WSP packages.

What should be installed on machine to fulfill these assumption?
I have read some articles about it, however none of them states what should be installed to create farm solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have Visual Studio 2012 with the Microsoft Office Developer Tools for VS  (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/office-dev-tools-for-visual-studio) and build farm solution (WSP) locally. You'll then need to deploy these solutions to your target test farm but that's definitively doable.

Most of the templates (new from VS 2012) will ask you to connect to a SharePoint server but you don't really need to have it locally.

In all scenario, you'll gain a lot of time to have a SP2013 environment "close to" your VS setup. And don't believe the hype, if you set things up properly, the little beast will work with even just 6gb of ram.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need a very good pc with alot of ram, a virtual machine to put on sharepoint, and finaly just sharepoint 2013.

```
http://blog.credera.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/SharePoint%202013%20Developer's%20Installation%20Guide%20by%20Credera.pdf
```

You can develope where you want aslong as you have the sharepoint dlls that you can add into visual studios!